Gnome Sudoku mouse
When trying to play the Gnome Sodoku on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I have to push really hard on the mouse button in any square to get anything to happen.  The mouse clicks work really well in all the rest of the computer.  At times the selected square will not turn blue to select a number either.  Something needs fixed.

As this issue appears only in that particular software I'd say you need to dive into the details there; i.e. this is not related to Ubuntu or Gnome, it is within "Gnome Sudoku". -> https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Sudoku or even https://gnome-sudoku.sourceforge.net/

Note though that this seems to be old and abandoned software.

of this is "old & abandoned" why is it still on the list to be downloaded??
